# How do I avoid repeating keyphrase in this scenario?

Tags: seo, wordpress, yoast

I'm working with a student on a project, The Bifrost Database of Gay Comic Characters, that indexes LGBTQ representation in mainstream American comic books https://bifrostdatabase.com/identity/all/). Our site includes approximately 90 comic book characters who fit various categories of LGBTQ identity. Other forums have blocked my post because referring to various identity facets is somehow a violation of community decency, so I will refer to these categories by color words: red, green, blue, and violet. So, red might refer to the 'l' and green might refer to the 'green.'

We are currently tweaking the pages to improve our position in Google search results by using the free version of the Yoast plugin. We're not hugely obsessed with SEO, but it would be nice to see our site coming up on the first page of results when people are posting relevant queries.

Here's the problem: We suspect that our most common use case is a situation in which a comic book fan or college student is trying to track down examples of positive representation in comic books. For example, someone might be searching for 'red comic characters' or 'green comic characters' rather than searching for a particular red or green comic character.

At first, I thought it would make sense for us to have a few different focus key phrases for different types of characters. So, all of the red characters might use the focus keyphrase 'red comic characters' and all of the green characters might use the focus keyphrase 'green comic characters.'

However, Yoast warns that it's not good to use the keyphrase more than once. Apparently, this will cause our pages to compete with each other.

The logical way to fix this problem would be to have highly unique keyphrases (e.g. "red character in Saga" or "green character in Thor") but this takes us further away from what we view as the most common usage scenario: students/fans trying to track down more general examples of positive representation.

Comment: Referring to gay, lesbian, bisexual, or other sexual identities is fine here and your posts won't get closed or deleted for using them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to avoid using that phrase on more thane one page, but you should have one page where it is used more prominently than other pages.   That page is the one and only page that should should receive special focus for that keyword.

It looks like you have such a page as sub-categories of the "View Characters" menu.  You should set the "green comic characters" as a key phase for the page that lists all of that type of character.    That page should use the phrase in its page title.  Currently your page title is "Green Archives - Bifrost Database", but you should change it to "Green Comic Characters - Bifrost Database"

Other pages on your site can use that phrase, but not prominently. It shouldn't be in the title or headings of other pages.  You should only add that phrase as a key phrase of the one page in Yoast.